# why is function returning undefined when finding === instead of 'YES' as return statement dictates?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a recursive function that will increment a value in a value pair and return 'YES' when on value is equal to the other value. I can console the pairs growing and eventually matching, but then the function ends with a value undefined.

```
function checkKanga(kangaArr) {
    if (kangaArr[0][0] > kangaArr[1][0]) return 'NO';
    if (kangaArr[0][0] === kangaArr[1][0]) return 'YES';
    kangaArr[0][0] += kangaArr[0][1];
    kangaArr[1][0] += kangaArr[1][1];
    checkKanga(kangaArr);
}

checkKanga([ [ 0, 3 ], [ 4, 2 ] ]);
```

I expect it to return 'YES' after running 4 times, but I only get undefined.

Comment: You aren't returning the recursive call.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return` the recursive call:

```
function checkKanga(kangaArr) {
    if (kangaArr[0][0] > kangaArr[1][0]) return 'NO';
    if (kangaArr[0][0] === kangaArr[1][0]) return 'YES';
    kangaArr[0][0] += kangaArr[0][1];
    kangaArr[1][0] += kangaArr[1][1];
    return checkKanga(kangaArr);
}
```

Demonstration:

```js
function checkKanga(kangaArr) {
    if (kangaArr[0][0] > kangaArr[1][0]) return 'NO';
    if (kangaArr[0][0] === kangaArr[1][0]) return 'YES';
    kangaArr[0][0] += kangaArr[0][1];
    kangaArr[1][0] += kangaArr[1][1];
    return checkKanga(kangaArr);
}

console.log(checkKanga([[0, 3], [4, 2]]));
```